# Create OpenVPN certificate valid for more than a year

Tags: openvpn

This command keeps generating the certificate valid only 365 days, no matter if I change the value to 100 or 3650 the result is same. 1 Year.
How can I generate the certificate valid for 10 years?

```
# openssl req -new -keyout newkey.pem -out newreq.pem -days 3650
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
...........................................................+++
.........................+++
writing new private key to 'newkey.pem'
Enter PEM pass phrase:
Verifying - Enter PEM pass phrase:
-----
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:AU
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:State
Locality Name (eg, city) []:City
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits PTY Ltd]:company
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:section
Common Name (eg, server FQDN or YOUR name) []:server
Email Address []:mail@example.com

Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
to be sent with your certificate request
A challenge password []:
An optional company name []:
# ./CA.sh -sign
Using configuration from /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
Enter pass phrase for ./demoCA/private/cakey.pem:
Check that the request matches the signature
Signature ok
Certificate Details:
        Serial Number:
            cb:32:13:1d:e2:40:2f:e4
        Validity
            Not Before: May 11 17:58:32 2021 GMT
            Not After : May 11 17:58:32 2022 GMT
        Subject:
            countryName               = AU
            stateOrProvinceName       = State
            localityName              = City
            organizationName          = company
            organizationalUnitName    = section
            commonName                = server
            emailAddress              = mail@example.com
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:FALSE
            Netscape Comment:
                OpenSSL Generated Certificate
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                E7:8A:D9:91:7C:81:BF:C0:CE:D9:43:D7:C8:D8:03:1C:60:85:D0:35
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:CF:76:53:4A:FB:01:EC:DE:CE:40:C1:F2:F0:F6:6E:12:57:24:8F:45

Certificate is to be certified until May 11 17:58:32 2022 GMT (365 days)
Sign the certificate? [y/n]:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some bizarro-world reason, you have to change the `default_days` in `openssl.cnf`, otherwise it overrides the `-days` command line option.

i.e. edit `openssl.conf` so that it has:

```
default_days = 3650
```

This seems intuitively and obviously wrong and contrary to reasonable expectations of how software defaults and command-line options should interact (and it is), but that's the way it works.

Comment: FWIW `man req` says, _**`-days n`** When the `-x509` option is being used this specifies the number of days to certify the certificate for, otherwise it is ignored. n should be a positive integer. The default is 30 days._ so although it's unexpected it is documented

Comment: @roaima you are totaly right, I did not used the -x509 option so -days are ignored. I should have at least get notified by the program, otherwise is just confusing. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @spaceman117X oh absolutely. A flag that's ignored _should_ trigger at least a warning if not an error. I completely agree with you and cas saying that it's ... wrong

Comment: Perhaps it was noted. I am getting `Ignoring -days; not generating a certificate` in the first line of output when trying the OP's command on Fedora.